# Como puedo usar una implementacion de una interface, solo incluyendo el .hpp de la interface?

Tags: c++, clase-abstracta, interface

## Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IWrittingDevice.hpp"
#include "IFactory.hpp"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    IFactory* factory = 0;
    IWrittingDevice* device = factory->create(0);
    device->Write();

    delete device;
    delete factory;

    return 0;
}
```

## IWrittingDevice.hpp

```
#pragma once 
struct IWrittingDevice {
    virtual void Write() = 0;
};
```

## Pen.hpp

```
#pragma once 
#include "IWrittingDevice.hpp"

struct Pen : IWrittingDevice
{
    Pen();
    virtual ~Pen();

    virtual void Write();
};
```

## Pen.cpp

```
#include "Pen.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Pen::Pen() { std::cout << "Constructor...\n";}

Pen::~Pen() { std::cout << "Destructor...\n";}

void Pen::Write() {
    std::cout << "Pen is wirtting...\n";
}
```

## Roller.hpp

```
#pragma once 
#include "IWrittingDevice.hpp"

struct Roller : IWrittingDevice {
    Roller();
    virtual ~Roller();

    virtual void Write();
};
```

## Roller.cpp

```
#include "Roller.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Roller::Roller() { std::cout << "Constructor...\n";}

Roller::~Roller() { std::cout << "Destructor...\n";}

void Roller::Write() {
    std::cout << "Roller is writting...\n";
}
```

## IFactory.hpp

```
#pragma once 
#include "IWrittingDevice.hpp"

struct IFactory {
    virtual IWrittingDevice* create(int) = 0;
};
```

## PenFactory.hpp

```
#pragma once 
#include "IFactory.hpp"
#include "Pen.hpp"

struct PenFactory : IFactory {
    virtual IWrittingDevice* create(int a = 0);
};
```

## PenFactory.cpp

```
#include "PenFactory.hpp"

IWrittingDevice* PenFactory::create(int a ) {
    return new Pen();
}
```

## RollerFactory.hpp

```
#pragma once 
#include "IFactory.hpp"
#include "Roller.hpp"

struct RollerFactory : IFactory {
    virtual IWrittingDevice* create(int b = 1);
};
```

## RollerFactory.cpp

```
#include "RollerFactory.hpp"

IWrittingDevice* RollerFactory::create(int b ) {
    return new Roller();
}
```

Comment: Sería de agradecer que publicases contenido en la pregunta. Texto, párrafos y cosas de esas que ayudan a que la pregunta sea legible y no haya que andar intuyendo qué es lo que debemos contestarte. Te he respondido esta vez pero espero que futuras preguntas mejoren en forma y contenido. Un saludo

Comment: Aun así sería recomendable que editases la pregunta y la adaptases a lo esperado para una pregunta de [es.so]. Te servirá para prácticar, conseguirás que la pregunta sea más legible y útil y evitará que te lleves negativos ocasionales

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error de concepto.

La interfaz tienes que verla como un contrato. Todas las clases que implementen una interfaz tienen, forzosamente, que implementar los métodos indicados en dicha interfaz.

Entonces, la interfaz por si misma no sabe qué hay que hacer con los argumentos que reciben las funciones que declara. De eso se van a encargar las clases que heredan de dicha interfaz.

Así pues, no puedes crear una interfaz directamente, sino que lo que creas es un objeto que hereda de la interfaz que necesitas.

Pues bien, una de las principales utilidades de las interfaces es que reducen el acoplamiento entre clases. Ya no necesitas saber qué objeto específico estás usando, sino que te guías única y exclusivamente por la lista de funciones que indica la interfaz de turno... pero tenemos el problema de que alguien, en alguna parte, tiene que encargarse de crear el objeto real que se debe usar en cada momento.

Una solución a este problema se encuentra en las llamadas factorías. Una factoría se utiliza para encapsular la creación de diferentes objetos (generalmente objetos con herencia común, ya sea clase base o interfaz). Entonces, la propia interfaz sí que debe saber qué objeto tiene que crear en cada momento... pero lo devuelve bajo la apariencia de la interfaz, luego el consumidor de la factoría no va a tener ni idea (ni tampoco lo necesita) acerca de la naturaleza propia del objeto devuelto por la factoría:

```
struct ILog
{
  virtual ~ILog() = default;
  virtual void Escribir(std::string const& datos) = 0;
};

struct LogAConsola : ILog
{
  void Escribir(std::string const& datos) override
  { std::cout << datos << '\n'; }
};

struct LogSilenciado: ILog
{
  void Escribir(std::string const& /* datos */) override
  { std::cout << "Log silenciado\n"; }
};

class FactoriaLog
{
public:
  static void SilenciarLog(bool valor)
  { silenciar_ = valor; }

  static std::unique_ptr<ILog> CrearLog()
  {
    if( silenciar_ )
      return std::make_unique<LogSilenciado>();
    else
      return std::make_unique<LogAConsola>();
  }

private:

  static bool silenciar_;
};

bool FactoriaLog::silenciar_ = false;
```

Vale, ¿y cómo usamos esta factoría? facil:

```
int main()
{
  FactoriaLog::SilenciarLog(false);

  std::unique_ptr<ILog> log = FactoriaLog::CrearLog();
  log->Escribir("Hola");

  FactoriaLog::SilenciarLog(true);
  log = FactoriaLog::CrearLog();

  log->Escribir("Hola");
}
```

Eso si, fíjate que la factoría no hereda de ninguna interfaz. Si la factoría heredase de una interfaz porque necesitamos cambiar de factoría, tendrímos que crear una suerte de factoría de factorías... el diseño se complicaría un rato.